# Loop two arrays and access one-at-a-time from first array and three-at-a-time from the second array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-insert

I have two sets of data which are in two different arrays and I need to combine them in groups then insert the results into my database.

```
// name values
$arr=['Ram','joy','Rahul','Monty'];
// values that need to be split between names
$code=['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21'];
```

In above I have two set of data.`$arr` contains the `name` and `$code` contains a numeric `code`.

Here I need to insert the code per name into the table as per the user input. Suppose `$userinput=2` the first 2 code will insert for name `Ram` in two row, then second two will insert for name `joy` and so on and if `$userinput=3` it will insert accordingly. My expected output for `$userinput=3` is given below.

```
_________________
 id   name   code
---+--------+-----
1  | Ram    | 10
---+--------+-----
2  | Ram    | 11
---+--------+-----
3  | Ram    | 12
---+--------+-----
4  | Joy    | 13
---+--------+-----
5  | Joy    | 14
---+--------+-----
6  | Joy    | 15
---+--------+-----
7  | Rahul  | 16
---+--------+-----
8  | Rahul  | 17
---+--------+-----
9  | Rahul  | 18
---+--------+-----
10 | Monty  | 19
---+--------+-----
11 | Monty  | 20
---+--------+-----
12 | Monty  | 21
---+--------+-----
```

Comment: this can be achieved using nested loop... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried something but its entering only 2 row always.

Comment: Do some math to divide `$code` by `$arr`, maybe throw in a `ceil()`, then loop, maybe reset an auto-increment value here and there...but I agree with @SamTengWong , you should show your try.

Comment: first do a `foreach` on your `$name` array.. then create a `counter` variable and do the second `foreach` on your `$code` array... every loop on your $code array increment the counter... if the counter is equal to $user_input.. cut the loop....

Comment: @AmitVisodiya likely has the answer, if not the closest. The `array_chunk()` is the key there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is...

I hope this helps you... I'm not on my laptop so this is what I could do..

```
    <?php

    $user_input = 3; // this should be your user input.
    $arr=['Ram','joy','Rahul','Monty'];
    $codes=['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21'];
    $counter1=0; //counter for your $codes to continue.
    foreach($arr as $name){
        $counter = 0; //counter for your condition...
        for($x=0; $x <= count($codes); $x++){
            $counter++;
            if($counter <= $user_input){
                echo "INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES ($name, $codes[$counter1])"."<br />";
            }else{
                break;
            }
            $counter1++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another I have tried answer is below.

```
$arr1=['Ram','joy','Rahul','Monty'];
$code1=['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21'];   
$userInput = 3;
$index = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{
    $count = 0;
    echo $arr1[$i]."<br>";
    for($j=0;$j<count($code1);$j++)
    {
        if($count != $userInput)
        {
            $key = $j+$index;
           if(array_key_exists($key,$code1))
           {
               //echo $code1[$j+$index]."<br>";
               echo "INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (".$arr1[$i].", ".$code1[$key].")" . "<br />";
               $count++;
           }
        }
        else
        {
            $index += $userInput;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Ram
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Ram, 10)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Ram, 11)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Ram, 12)
joy
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (joy, 13)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (joy, 14)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (joy, 15)
Rahul
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Rahul, 16)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Rahul, 17)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Rahul, 18)
Monty
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Monty, 19)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Monty, 20)
INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES (Monty, 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, assuming you're using PDO as your DataBase connection.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($code); $i++) {
  $db->query("INSERT INTO db_code (name, code) VALUES ('{$arr[$i]}', '{$code[$i]}'"); 
}
```

Of course, if you haven't set up the `$db` function, or a `handler`, just add:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=DATABASE_HOST;dbname=DATBASE_NAME", DATABSE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
```

And for most users, the `host = localhost, name = your databse to enter to, username = root, password = nothing`.

If you want more information on PDO, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: The asker is trying to access one element from `$arr` and three elements from `$codes`.  This answer is not suitable for the described task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-sql statement solution:

```
$arr    =   array('Ram','joy','Rahul','Monty');
$code   =   array('10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21');

function qAssemble($arr,$code)
    {
        $split  =   array_chunk($code,ceil((count($code) / count($arr))));
        $new    =   array();
        foreach($arr as $k=>$name) {
            $b      =   array_filter($split[$k]);
            $a      =   array_fill(0,count($b),$name);
            $new    =   array_merge($new,array_map(function($v) use ($name)
                {
                    return "('{$name}','{$v}')";
                },$b));
        }

        return implode(',',$new);
    }

$str    =   "insert into `db_code` (`name`, `code`) VALUES ".qAssemble($arr,$code);

print_r($str);
```

Gives you:

```
insert into `db_code` (`name`, `code`) VALUES ('Ram','10'),('Ram','11'),('Ram','12'),('joy','13'),('joy','14'),('joy','15'),('Rahul','16'),('Rahul','17'),('Rahul','18'),('Monty','19'),('Monty','20'),('Monty','21')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
        $arr = ['Ram', 'joy', 'Rahul', 'Monty'];
        $code = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'];
        $userInput = 3;
        $new_code = array_chunk($code, $userInput);
        $final = array_combine($arr, $new_code);
        foreach ($final as $name => $code_array) {
            echo "INSERT INTO sampletable (`name`, `code`) VALUES ($name, $code_array[0]]), ($name, $code_array[1]]), ($name, $code_array[2]])" . "<br />";
        }
```

Comment: just to set it dynamic like  $userInput = 3; $new_code = array_chunk($code, $userInput); @Sam Teng Wong

Comment: @RuchishParikh no...., he set the values to be static.... if I put 2.. there should be only two insert values..... as you can see there there are three and it is fix...

Comment: @RuchishParikh still wrong... what array_chunk do is divide the $code to every $arr... so if I put 3... it'll divide equally.. it is correct because 12/3 = 4.. however if I put 2 as a userinput there.. what will happen to 18 to 21?

Comment: yes. its create issue at that time. Error : array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements. Correct @SamTengWong. Please check my new answer which I have tried.

Comment: You can use `array_fill()` to make the arrays even so you can combine them.